# If response equals value, then value equals""

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to add this to my script so when there response is let's say "area T/L", then area T/L would equal a "name" (lets say jack for example" i use this script now it works great just would like to be able to edit response before they are sent spreadsheet

here is what i have

```
 response = itemResponse.getResponse().toString();  // get the corresponding answer
 if (typeof response === 'undefined') response = '';
```

the full script

```
 function onSubmit(e) {
 var myemail = "processauditdatabase@gmail.com"  // please, replace myemail by your email 
  try{
  var formResponse = e.response;//get the form response
  var editResponseUrl = formResponse.getEditResponseUrl(); //get the individual form url just in case the       respondent needs to edit its anwers later
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();// get all item questions and anwers
  var itemResponse
  var title
  var response
  for (var i = 0; i < itemResponses.length; i++) {    // iterate for all form items
    itemResponse = itemResponses[i];
    title = itemResponse.getItem().getTitle().toUpperCase(); // get the question title. In our form can be    EMAIL or NAME
    response =  itemResponse.getResponse().toString();  // get the corresponding answer
    if (typeof response === 'undefined') response = '';
    if(title.indexOf("AUDITOR", 0) != -1){   // if the title is "AUDITOR NAME"
      var auditor = response.toUpperCase();  // get it
    }
    else if (title.indexOf("JCI", 0) != -1){  // if the title is "STATION NAME"
      var work = response.toUpperCase(); // get it
    }
    else if (title.indexOf("RELATED", 0) != -1){  // if the title is "ISSUES FOUND"
      var found = response.toUpperCase(); // get it
    }
    else if (title.indexOf("DEPARTMENT", 0) != -1){  // if the title is "DEPARTMENT RESPONSIBLE"
      var department = response.toUpperCase(); // get it
    }
    else if (title.indexOf("RESULTS", 0) != -1){  // if the title is "NAME"
      var results = response.toUpperCase(); // get it
      }
  }
  var subject = results + ",\n\n"; // body of the message you're assembling
  subject += "Process Confirmation Audit, \n\n"; // body of the message you're assembling
  subject += department + ",\n\n"; // body of the message you're assembling
  var message = auditor + ",\n\n"; // body of the message you're assembling
  message += "Just Completed Station Audit \n\n"; // body of the message you're assembling
  message += work + ",\n\n"; // body of the message you're assembling
  message += "FAILED AUDIT ISSUES FOUND:\n\n"; // body of the message you're assembling
  message += found + ",\n\n"; // body of the message you're assembling
  message += "Please Assign Ownership For This Issue:\n\n"; // body of the message you're assembling
  message += "Click On The Link Below To Review/Assign Ownership Responsibilites:\n\n"; // body of the message you're assembling
  message += editResponseUrl + "\n\n"; // body of the message you're assembling
  MailApp.sendEmail("processauditdatabase@gmail.com", subject, message); // send the message
 }
 catch(e) {             // if something wrong happens 
  MailApp.sendEmail(myemail, "Error in Auto replying to contact form submission.", e.message); // tell me
  }
 }
```

Comment: Tried to help you with my aswear if is not clear provide more details about the value of the variables itemResponse and the result of the getResponse() call. Best, Br Araujo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You logic is okey but we have some problems.
response you never be undefined in this case.
Maybe you are getting an error "something is not defined".

Check if itemResponse and getResponse are returning defined values and than check if response is empty comparing it to "".

You can use like this

```
...
response =  itemResponse.getResponse().toString();  // get the corresponding answer
if (response === 'area1 T/L') response = '';
...
```

Comment: i would get undefined if the response is left empty, so in this case it works, i use the undefined as a fliter for email as an obsolete email and send to trash.  the whole script i am using is below, so what i am trying to accomplish is when someone chooses let's say "area1 T/L" in the response field of the form, i would like the form response to read as follows if (typeof response==='area1 T/L') response ='jack smith'; so that way when it sends an email it will say jack smith instead of area1 T/L.  here is the full script i edit my post above

Comment: So let's change your code to if(response == "area1 T/L") . Do you know how to use typeof operator? It's used to get the type of some variable. In the example that you gave if response is filled it you return only "string" as it will be response type.

Comment: would i put that under 'var results ='

Comment: I changed the response, please check if you understood

Comment: that worked great, now if i wanted to add another if(response===   would i just use a "else if"    thanks so much for the help, greatly appreciated

Comment: i used the else and figured it out so thanks for the help , you helped me out greatly